# Show tags for each file in Finder icon view

Tags: finder, software-recommendation, finder-tag

**Goal**: In macOS Monterey, using the Finder icon view, I want to show three things *for each file*, listed below. I want them close together visually. I only can show the first two, not the third:

- ☑︎ icon
- ☑︎ filename
- ☐ its tags

**Workaround**: the only way I know to see tags is by having the preview sidebar open. I don’t like this because I can’t quickly see all the tags for the files.

**Questions**:

- Is it currently possible (or not) to show the tags like I want?
- Is there some other way to accomplish a similar goal: seeing all tags for each file in a Finder view?
- Do you highly recommend another program to accomplish this?

So far, I've had no luck yet finding this on the splinternets.

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot? I don't have Monterey yet, but previously in icon view, the tag colour is shown to the left of the name.

Answer (score 1):

Short answers to your three questions:

1. It is not possible to show (non-coloured) tags in Finder's Icon View.
2. Finder's List View can show additional columns, including tags. That is a simple way to show tags for all files in a folder or in search results.
3. [Leap](https://ironicsoftware.com) from Ironic Software (the key pioneer in developing Mac OS X tags) can show tags just below file icons. If you make serious/heavy use of tags for file management, I highly recommend Leap.

Answer (score 0):

I don't use Tags but desired functionality (as I understand it) work out of box in Monterey:

- files/folders must have associated Tags
- switch to `as Icons` view

Colored circles will be displayed below icon and before file/folder name:

[image]

Comment: That is only the colour tags.

Comment: @Gilby - aren’t “only the colour tags” tags? I tried to find reference to “only the text of tags” in OP post but couldn’t find.